# Don't know what to do after failing to stitch images with all the stitching algorithms that I've got

Tags: algorithm, opencv, opencv-stitching

I have been trying to stitch four images that I got from a 360 camera (it is composed of four small cameras giving me each one an image corresponding to a 90 degree angle) using some algorithms that I have found online, and also using OpenCV's stitching algorithm. I could use these codes to stitch some images that I have gotten on the web, but failed when I tried with the images produced from my 360 camera.

When trying to stitch my images, all of the codes with no exception crashed. Using OpenCV's algorithm, the error message that I got was:

`Can't stitch images, error code = 1` which means that I have not enough features between the image intersections.

What I wonder is that I should forget about software (since every code works for a scope of images), and start to think whether my images have features enough for the stitch process. Therefore, I am considering abandoning the idea of creating this kind of adjustment for this hardware. "The way that this camera produces images simply gives me not enough features in between each of the images for a stitching process to be done." that's the thought that I came to realize.

Should I conclude that?

Comment: It appears the software you're trying is using image features to create an exact alignment. If there's no significant overlap between the camera fields of view, this won't work. You'll need to develop another method of aligning the camera images. Good luck!

Comment: As a rule of thumb you want about 20-30% overlap on images for the feature recognition and alignment to work with. Can you maybe rotate the 4 cameras through 45 degrees and take a second set?

Comment: Hi! Actually the software that I am using does not create an exact alignment. Also, I concluded that each image has something around 10% of features overlapping (but not exact overlapping i.e. they aren't totally aligned) with the next one. Regarding your idea, I did this same experiment rotating the set by 45 degrees (they are always at the same position in respect to each other) which gave me 8 images. Unfortunately, openCV's algorithm worked just for images 1-2 and 7-8. All the others have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

`Can't stitch images, error code = 1` happens on `cv::Stitcher` when `cpp-example-stitching` is not able to detect common points between the images you provided. Usually this is because they don't overlap enough.

I don't know if that's the only case when the error will happen, but that's one of the cases.

Comment: `Overlap region` is the important point. Features' overlapping caused the stitching algorithm to return the `0` status in my case. Thanks!